# Angular 4 Child Routing is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

everyone.
I'm working with angular but I've some issues with the routing.
I've followed some tutorials, but the routing is not working.
Can somebody check my code and tell me what I'm doing worse?

This is my principal router module:

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ListadoSolicitudComponent } from './solicitudes/listado_solicitud.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'solicitud', loadChildren: './solicitudes/solicitudes.module#SolicitudesModule' },
 { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './administracion/administracion.module#AdministracionModule' },
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
 { path: 'solicitudes', component: ListadoSolicitudComponent },
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/solicitudes', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{ }
```

My principal module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { Contenedor } from './contenedor.component';
import { SolicitudesModule } from './solicitudes/solicitudes.module';
import { AdministracionModule } from './administracion/administracion.module';
import { AppRoutingModule }  from './app-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ListadoSolicitudComponent } from './solicitudes/listado_solicitud.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [Contenedor, LoginComponent, ListadoSolicitudComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule/*, SolicitudesModule, AdministracionModule*/],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [Contenedor]
})
export class ContenedorModule { }
```

And, this is one of the two router child module (SolicitudesRutaModule):

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

//Importo los componentes
import { ListadoSolicitudComponent } from './listado_solicitud.component';

import { registrosolicitud } from './registro_solicitud.component';
import { RegistroParticipantes } from './registro_participantes.component';
import { Proyeccion } from './proyeccion_gastos.component';
import { DatoSolicitud } from './datos_solicitud.component';
import { ordencompra } from './orden_compra_solicitud.component';
import { Bitacora } from './bitacora.component';
import { AprobarSolicitud } from './aprobar.component';
import { editarsolicitud } from './editar_solicitud.component';

const Route: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ListadoSolicitudComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'registro', component: registrosolicitud },
    { path: 'gasto', component: Proyeccion },
    { path: 'participantes', component: RegistroParticipantes },
    { path: 'compra', component: ordencompra },
    { path: 'bitacora', component: Bitacora },
    { path: 'aprobar', component: AprobarSolicitud },
    { path: 'edit', component: editarsolicitud }
  ]}
];
// Metadatos del módulo
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(Route) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class SolicitudesRutaModule { }
```

Comment: Can you define "not working"? -- What about it is not working? What is currently happening, and what is the expected result?

Comment: When I push the button to change the view, nothing happens. I can move between the login and ListadoSolicitud, but I can't go to "registro", compra", etcetera (the components in the Child Routing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not import the SolicitudesRutaModule.

In your `AppRoutingModule`, you should do:

```
{ path: 'solicitudes', loadChildren: 'path/to/module#SolicitudesRutaModule' },
```

Note that if `registro` is a child of the default route `''` in your `SolicitudesRutaModule`, the `ListadoSolicitudComponent` should have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in its template.
If this is not the case, put the other routes like `registro` in the same array as the default route `''`.

Comment: Did this help you? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: it seems that I've not the level necesary to vote if is helful or not. But it was. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad to hear. Yes, you cannot vote yet, but you can accept the answer with the check symbol next to it if it solved your problem. :)